# Compute 3 Month return for dataframe of monthly returns

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe of monthly stock returns:

```
d<-data.frame(replicate(5,sample(rnorm(1),6,rep=TRUE)))
```

Now I would like to transform these returns to n-month returns in the following manner (e.g. for n=3):

```
d[1,1]=(1+d[1,1])*(1+d[2,1])*(1+d[3,1])
d[2,1]=(1+d[2,1])*(1+d[3,1])*(1+d[4,1])
d[3,1]=(1+d[3,1])*(1+d[4,1])*(1+d[5,1])
```

And then the same for the next column:

```
d[1,2]=(1+d[1,2])*(1+d[2,2])*(1+d[3,2])
d[2,2]=(1+d[2,2])*(1+d[3,2])*(1+d[4,2])
d[3,2]=(1+d[3,2])*(1+d[4,2])*(1+d[5,2])
```

I think you get the idea.

Now, the way I was thinking to proceed is as follows:

```
apply(d, 2, fun)
```

where fun is defined as:

```
fun<-function(df_column)
{
  # Loop over df_column rows
 for (row in 1:nrow(df_column)) {
   d[row]=(1+d[row])*(1+d[row+1])*(1+d[row+2])
 }
}
```

Does this approach make sense or is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `rollapply` in one of these forms depending on what it is you prefer. The first puts NAs in the last two rows.  The second fills them with partial products and the third drops the last two rows.  The 3 argument specifies the width of the rolling product and could be changed if you want to try other widths.  See `?rollapply` for more info.

```
library(zoo)

rollapplyr(d + 1, 3, prod, align = "left", fill = NA)

rollapplyr(d + 1, 3, prod, align = "left", partial = TRUE)

rollapplyr(d + 1, 3, prod, align = "left")
```

Comment: I've not seen that function used from `zoo`, I like how easy it is to reason about. Out of curiosity I did notice it was much slower than the `map` solution and was curious why that was the case.

Comment: It is geared toward zoo objects and converts the object internally to zoo and then back and is written in R.   Also it is very general.  You could try `exp(rollsum(log(1+d), 3, align = "left", fill = NA))` which knows the function ahead of time and so can be faster.  Also there is the RcppRoll package which has some rolling functions written in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `purrr::map_df` and `dplyr::lead` to achieve what you are after.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(replicate(5, rnorm(6)))

df %>%
  map_df(function(x) {

    (1 + x) * (1 + lead(x, 1)) * (1 + lead(x, 2))

  })

# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#          X1       X2         X3         X4         X5
#       <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 1.4068610 6.863243 -0.2430606 -2.3172461  1.2246900
# 2 0.9688954 2.561324  1.0225645 -1.2568729 -0.3228241
# 3 3.1256224 6.520767  1.0148172 -0.4485965 -0.8276191
# 4 2.0496361 7.100212 -1.9395879 -1.4328679 -0.4011510
# 5        NA       NA         NA         NA         NA
# 6        NA       NA         NA         NA         NA
```

> **N.B.** As you are looking ahead two records, note that the final two rows will only produce `NA`. You could add `na.omit` or `tidyr::drop_na` to your pipe if you want them to be excluded.

Comment: Also very nice. Thank you Kevin!!